# Angular application built with esbuild use browser directory as output

Tags: angular, esbuild

I just upgraded an application to angular 17 where the angular.json configuration is the following:

```
"outputPath": "../SFPD.Workflows/wwwroot",
```

It's important that the compiled application goes into this directory, however, when using esbuild, it goes into "../SFPD.Workflows/wwwroot/browser" and I can't find the setting to ensure that the "browser" directory is not appended.

Comment: For those who endup here, OP opened an issue on the Angular CLI repo : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/26304

Answer (score 6):

According to the mentioned Bug Ticket, a solution has now been implemented and is available in Angular>=17.1.x

```json
            "outputPath": {
              "base": "dist/project-name",
              "browser": ""
            },
```

If you keep the browser property empty, the path will be compatible to the previous versions without the browser directory.